# Changing a value in a CSV returns a 0 length file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a script that changes a value in a column to '1'. However, the script writes a zero length file. I did some write-host to make sure that data should actually be piped to Export-Csv but still its only outputting a zero length file.

````
Import-Csv D:\sysutil\scratch\rap7logs\csv\noxsv.05-01-20.csv | 
Foreach-Object  {
$_.'result' = '1' 
#write-host $_.'timestamp'
#write-host $_.'destination_user'
#write-host $_.'result'
} | Export-Csv  D:\sysutil\scratch\rap7logs\csv\noxsv.05-01-20a.csv -NoTypeInformation```
````

Comment: What is the CSV file?

Comment: You need to output `$_` from `Foreach-Object`.  As it is, it is piping nothing to `Export-Csv`.

Answer (score 1):

`Export-Csv` will operate on what's piped to it by `Foreach-Object`, however your `Foreach-Object` is performing an action with no output, so there's nothing for `Export-Csv` to write.

You need to have `Foreach-Object` output the same input object like this...

```bsh
Foreach-Object  {
    $_.'result' = '1'

    $_
}
```

...or like this...

```bsh
Foreach-Object  {
    $_.'result' = '1'

    return $_
}
```

...in order for the modified object to make it to `Export-Csv`.

Comment: That's explained in the first sentence, or are you asking why `ForEach-Object` doesn't automatically output the same input object?

Comment: I was really asking why the foreach doesnt output the object, in particular if modifications the object are made. But at the end of the day it doesnt really matter. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Well, in the case of modifying `$_.'result'` which object/value would it output? `$_.'result'` or `$_`? In some cases it's desirable for `ForEach-Object` to produce no output, so how would it tell when to automatically pass through the input and when not? Also, that `{ }` parameter is just a common `ScriptBlock` (see `help about_script_blocks`), which would be treated as opaque by `ForEach-Object`; it doesn't know or care what's going on inside, it just executes it. So, the answer is you need to make your intentions explicit because there's not really a reliable, one-size-fits-all alternative.